# No module named keras.api Mask R CNN

Tags: keras, matterport

I am in the demo file of the Mask R CNN repo from matterport. Trying to run the first cell but encountering the following error. I have keras 2.3.0 installed. Running Python 3.8. The below is a trace of the error from the model.py file inside the Mask R CNN repo, which came with the clone. Thanks!

The repo referred to is here: https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN.git

### Thank you all for your kind support.

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_3220/983756133.py in <module>
      7 import matplotlib
      8 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 9 import keras
     10 
     11 # Root directory of the project

~\OneDrive\New Project\myenv1\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py in <module>
      1 from __future__ import absolute_import
      2 
----> 3 from . import utils
      4 from . import activations
      5 from . import applications

~\OneDrive\New Project\myenv1\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py in <module>
     24 from .layer_utils import get_source_inputs
     25 from .layer_utils import print_summary
---> 26 from .vis_utils import model_to_dot
     27 from .vis_utils import plot_model
     28 from .np_utils import to_categorical

~\OneDrive\New Project\myenv1\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\vis_utils.py in <module>
      5 
      6 import os
----> 7 from ..models import Model
      8 from ..layers.wrappers import Wrapper
      9 

~\OneDrive\New Project\myenv1\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py in <module>
     10 from .engine.input_layer import Input
     11 from .engine.input_layer import InputLayer
---> 12 from .engine.training import Model
     13 from .engine.sequential import Sequential
     14 from .engine.saving import save_model

~\OneDrive\New Project\myenv1\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\__init__.py in <module>
      6 from .base_layer import Layer
      7 from .network import get_source_inputs
----> 8 from .training import Model

~\OneDrive\New Project\myenv1\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in <module>
     12 from .network import Network
     13 from .base_layer import Layer
---> 14 from . import training_utils
     15 from . import training_arrays
     16 from . import training_generator

~\OneDrive\New Project\myenv1\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py in <module>
     15 from .. import backend as K
     16 from .. import losses
---> 17 from .. import metrics as metrics_module
     18 from ..utils import Sequence
     19 from ..utils import generic_utils

~\OneDrive\New Project\myenv1\lib\site-packages\keras\metrics.py in <module>
   1848     import tensorflow as tf
   1849     if tf.__version__ >= '2.0.0':
-> 1850         BaseMeanIoU = tf.keras.metrics.MeanIoU
   1851 
   1852 

~\OneDrive\New Project\myenv1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\lazy_loader.py in __getattr__(self, item)
     60 
     61   def __getattr__(self, item):
---> 62     module = self._load()
     63     return getattr(module, item)
     64 

~\OneDrive\New Project\myenv1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\lazy_loader.py in _load(self)
     43     """Load the module and insert it into the parent's globals."""
     44     # Import the target module and insert it into the parent's namespace
---> 45     module = importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
     46     self._parent_module_globals[self._local_name] = module
     47 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py in import_module(name, package)
    125                 break
    126             level += 1
--> 127     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    128 
    129 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.api'
```

Answer (score 0):

I read the repo that you have referred. You maybe try run your code with environment below:

- Python 3.4, TensorFlow 1.3, Keras 2.0.8

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a shot